# Wordpress rewrite non_wp_rules

Tags: wordpress

This is my code: (use default wp theme: twentyfourteen)

```
function my_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $non_wp_rules = array(
        'assets/(.*)'  => 'wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/assets/$1',
    );

    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules = $non_wp_rules + $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules;
}

function my_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_flush_rewrite_rules');
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules');
```

now, i visit link:

```
mysite.domain/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/assets/css/global.css => //yes, base css file
mysite.domain/assets/css/global.css => //not working
```

somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak the rewrite rule slightly

```
$non_wp_rules = array(
    'css/(.*)'  => 'wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/assets/css/$1',
    'js/(.*)'  => 'wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/assets/js/$1',
);
```